# Adding values per unique customer together with sumif

Tags: excel, sumifs

I have a list of customers and values looking something like this

```
JeffJohnson, Coke, 2.5
JeffJohnson, Sandwich, 6
JennyWilson, Donut, 3
```

What I want is a list of total by customer looking like this

```
JeffJohnson, 8.5
JeffJohson, 8.5
JennyWilson, 3
```

I tried using =sumif (a:a, b1, c:c) but it is not working. 
I need it to work for quite a few lines without manually adding the query.

Any ideas?

Comment: sumif should be what you want. Assuming you start on row 1 AND you have your data in columns A:C, AND you have a summary table with each name from column A in column D, and you want to put the sum in column E, the formula in cell E1 would be `SUMIF(A:A,D1,C:C)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SUMIF()` criteria need to change to `A1` instead of `B1`. See below

```
=SUMIF(A:A,A1,C:C)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Def the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1=$A$1:$A$3)*$C$1:$C$3)
```

[image]